# Mobile Services: How to handle the case where your query string is too long?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, offline-mode

With Azure Mobile Services Offline Support I'm issuing a PullAsync query like so:

```
// This list contains 53 emails
var deviceContactEmails = new List<string> { "derek@gmail.com", "sarah@gmail.com", ... };
var query = _userTable.Where(x => deviceContactEmails.Contains(x.Email));
await _userTable.PullAsync(query);
```

The Mobile Services SDK translates query into a URL encoded GET request with a filter like so (this was a list of 60 emails used for the Contains but I cut out a lot of the middle for brevity):

```
https://rememberwhen.azure-mobile.net/tables/User?$filter=((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((email%20eq%20'carlin_jmecwrv_stulberg%40tfbnw.net')%20or%20(email%20eq%20'carlin_jmecwrv_stulberg%40tfbnw.net'))%20or%20(email%20eq%20'carlin_jmecwrv_stulberg%40tfbnw.net'))%20eq%20'carlin_jmecwrv_stulberg%40tfbnw.net'))%20or%20(email%20eq%20'carlin_jmecwrv_stulberg%40tfbnw.net'))&$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true&__systemproperties=__createdAt%2C__version
```

The problem is that if deviceContactEmails is too long, the service will complain about the query string length. Trying to filter on this many items in the URL is a problem, so I need to filter by passing the items in the body of the request with JSON or some other way.

So I guess the question is: How do I correctly set this up using the Mobile Service SDK with offline support so I can avoid exceeding the limit on the query string length in the URL encoded request?

Comment: The limit for `in` operators in this context is quite large.  Can you clarify how many elements are in `deviceContractEmails` when it fails?

Comment: Only 53. The error does mention I can increase the query string length but that doing so is a security risk..

Comment: Where does "query string length" come into play with your code? What code is this?  Client-code?  Server-side-code?  I am mystified how "query string length" could be relevant here; your `deviceContactEmails` appears to be constructed server-side, in which case that error would be a red herring.

Comment: This is client code that is pulling down data from Azure using an IMobileServiceSyncTable. deviceContactEmails is a list that is built client side. The issue is that the LINQ query is converted into an URL encoded GET which results in the query string being too long. I'm updating the question with more info now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I need to create a custom API to send the list of emails as the body of the request. I'll update this answer and accept if I solve it.